Archive pollutants measurements in Europe
I am looking for historical dataset of air pollutants and PM in Europe. Since EU is a union, I would like to ask if there is a common (and preferrably updated) base for measurements of air pollutants. I know about a mobile application of EEA and some maps (European Environmental Agency) but I am looking for datasets about the measurements of air pollutants.
